# Is there a dual notion for the Nerve functor?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Say in the most classical case, we probe a topological space $X$ by the n-simplices $\Delta^n$ by using the nerve functor $Hom_{Top}(-,X)$. Is another functor $Hom_{Top}(X,-)$ of any use, or is there a dual notion for the nerve functor? Why its left adjoint geometric realization has a dual called totalization? Thank you so much?

Comment: Do you mean singular simplicial set instead of nerve? The nerve is usually a functor from categories to simplicial sets, not from spaces.

Comment: Nerve in a general sense: 
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+and+realization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to work in an appropriate homotopy category instead of Top, you can take K to be the Eilenberg Maclane spectrum so that Hom(X,K) is (for reasonable X) the singular cohomology of X.

Comment: ... or if your willing to go further and drink the derived cool-aid, you can just use the spectrum Hom(X,K) which is a module for the ring spectrum K=HZ and represents the total singular cohomology complex. Or even better, let K range over all spectra. Then you get all generalized cohomology theories this way!